# WinJS System.Launcher only working in debug mode

Tags: visual-studio-2012, microsoft-metro, winjs

The following code works flawlessly when run in debug mode (F5) .. but when deployed (as a app tile) or run without the debugger (ctl+f5), it does **not** work properly.

*behaviour expected/ when working:* clicking the tile launches the steam url link immediately, without rendering the html page visibly.

*behaviour received/ not working:* clicking the tile launches the app, only rendering the html page and never launches the steam url.

```
var mydefs = new Object();
mydefs = { url: 'steam://rungameid/200710' };

function launch(url) {
    var uri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri(url);

    Windows.System.Launcher.launchUriAsync(uri).then(
         function (success) {
             if (success) {
                 // File launched
                 window.close();
             } else {
                 // File launch failed
             }
         });
}

(function () {
    "use strict";

    WinJS.Binding.optimizeBindingReferences = true;

    var app = WinJS.Application;
    var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;

    app.onactivated = function (args) {
        if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
            launch(mydefs.url);

            args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll());
        }
    };

    app.oncheckpoint = function (args) {
        window.close();
    };

    app.start();
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a timing issue. The following works for me as a tile

```
(function () {
   "use strict";
    var mydefs = new Object();
    mydefs = { url: 'steam://rungameid/200710' };

    WinJS.Namespace.define("Steam", {
      launch: function launch(url) {
        var uri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri(url);

        Windows.System.Launcher.launchUriAsync(uri).then(
             function (success) {
                 if (success) {
                     // File launched
                     window.close();
                 } else {
                     // File launch failed
                 }
             });
          }
  });


  WinJS.Binding.optimizeBindingReferences = true;

  var app = WinJS.Application;
  var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;

  app.onactivated = function (args) {
    if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {                 
        setTimeout('Steam.launch("steam://rungameid/200710");', 2000);
        args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll());
    }
  };

  app.start();
})();
```

Comment: this does it, thank you. -- the only thing left is that the behaviour is still not the same as when run from debug: the app remains running/open even after launching the steam url. I'm sure I will figure it out though; this was a great answer thanks.

Comment: This works but isn't ideal. Does anyone know the technical reason this is required?

Comment: I thought it might be fixed using `setImmediate` but that doesn't seem to be the case. It could have been working for me because my app was loading quickly, but I tested more and found it wasn't working still. The only thing that works right now is a timeout.